# Remove all objects in repo but specified object

Tags: bash, git

I'm trying to write a program that will get an object from github, without cloning the entire repo. The last line does not work, giving me 
 a `Syntax error: "(" unexpected`. It is supposed to remove all files / directories except for that.

```
#!/bin/sh
object=$2 #sets item not to remove as second argument
address=$1 #sets github address (github.com/user/repo)
git clone $1 #clones it
location="${address##*/}" #gets part after last backslash
cd $location #cd's into it

#Syntax error: "(" unexpected
rm -rf !("$object")
```

Comment: What are you expecting that line to do?  Perhaps you're trying to use bash's extglobs, in which case you'll need to use `bash` not `sh` and enable them with `shopt -s extglob`

Comment: changed the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extglob syntax for `bash` is not enabled by default, and that's what will give you the `!(...)` syntax.  You'll have to turn it on if you want, by first changing your shebang to use bash

```
#! /bin/bash
```

then by turning on extglob by adding

```
shopt -s extglob
```

somewhere before that line